# Jsoup: Login into site with a post key that changes on each connect?

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I am trying to do an automated login for the site: https://my.calpoly.edu.

The site's login form has a key that changes on each request of the site:

Is there anyway to get around this? I am able to scrape all the input elements and store them into a map then send a POST request on a second connection, but I believe it is not working because on the second connection, the lt request changes.

Here's my code:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://my.calpoly.edu/").get();
    Element loginForm = doc.getElementById("fm1");
    Elements inputElements = loginForm.getElementsByTag("input");
    HashMap<String, String> paramList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = URLEncoder.encode(inputElement.attr("value"), "UTF-8");

        if (key.equals("username")) {
            value = "user123";
        }
        else if (key.equals("password")) {
            value = "pass123";
        }

        paramList.put(key, value);
    }

    //Iterator it = paramList.entrySet().iterator();
    //while (it.hasNext()) {
    //    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    //   System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + "=" + pairs.getValue());
    //}

    Connection res = Jsoup.connect("https://my.calpoly.edu/cas/login");
    res.data(paramList);
    res.method(Method.POST);
    res.userAgent("Mozilla");
    Response response = res.execute();
    System.out.println(response.body());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the document like this:

```
Connection connect = Jsoup.connect("https://my.calpoly.edu/");
Document doc = connect.get();
```

And then, for your second connection, use the same object, so the request wont change:

```
  Connection res = connect;
```

Or, you can use directly `connect` object also.

Comment: Ah Genius! I've made the changes, but unfortunately, it is still not logging me in. Any ideas what I could be missing? My post map shows:


username=user123

submit=Sign+In

_eventId=submit
lt=_cE46BE4A1-10D5-2F9D-EC72-CC2DE2A62867_k7EE63C6A-9611-6818-2E0E-9A057AD1237E
password=pass123

Comment: @MichaelWong which tags are you comparing??